# is it possible to input a question into the console, and have it return the correct answer?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, methods

First let's look at 3 Example questions and Answers:

```
    String[] questions = new String[3];
    questions[0] = "What is the first letter in the alphabet?";
    questions[1] = "What is two plus two?";
    questions[2] = "What planet do we live on?";

    String[] answers = new String[3];
    answers[0] = "A";
    answers[1] = "four";
    answers[2] = "Earth";
```

So the idea is that the code has all the questions that I could ask, and I want the console to return back the correct answer that corresponds to the correct question

So an Example that works:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[1])){
        System.out.println(answers[1]);
} else {
        System.out.println("Question is unknown");
    }
```

With this only if type "What is two plus two" it will answer "four"
However, that is only because the question is specifically written in the code

So if I want all of the questions I have written it multiple times:

```
    if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[0])){
        System.out.println(answers[0]);
} else {
        System.out.println("Question is unknown");
    }

    if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[1])){
        System.out.println(answers[1]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Question is unknown");
    }

    if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[2])){
        System.out.println(answers[2]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Question is unknown");
    }
```

What I need is for the console to look through all the questions in one go.
I don't know how to either have the input equal quesions[0 through x(however many there are)] or somehow make the if/else statements in a for loop so i don't have to write them all individually, I feel like a method could help, but I'm not too sure where to go from this point.

Thank you to whoever decides to help me, I feel like it's close but I'm just missing a little something :/

Comment: Use a for loop. The loop variable can provide an index into your arrays.

Comment: Or use a `Map<String><String>`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you could use a for loop and compare the input to the question at each index

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();

String[] questions = new String[3];
String[] answers = new String[3];

//Explained lower down
boolean questionFound = false;

//Iterate through the whole questions list
for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  //Compare input question to each question in the list and if
  //it is equal then print out the answer
  if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(questions[i])) {
    System.out.println(answers[i]);
    questionsFound = true;
    break;

  }
}
//And then for the question not found, I'm sure there is a better way, but all I can think about is a boolean flag right now.
if (!questionFound) {
  System.out.println("Question not found");
}
```

Comment: why keep looping when you have found the question?